# How to add a block in a available space given an array of blocks in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a grid that may start off at some initial state represented by "myblocks". I want to add a new squares or rectangles in empty space by clicking on a button "#addBlockButton" only if:

> 1) There is available space in the grid. 
>   2) The available space meets
>   the minimum block size defined by "min_width" and "min_height".

The block added will be added to available space, or alert "no space available" if there is no available space.

The blockCounter is just a unique identifier that autoincrements.

Assuming I have a grid of size 10x10 and minimum block size is:

```
let grid_width = 10
let grid_height = 10
let block_min_width = 2
let block_min_height = 2
```

I have an array of blocks "myblocks" like this:

Example:
This is a single block that takes up the entire grid.

```
myblocks = [{
'blockCounter':1,
'x': 0,
'y': 0,
'height': 10
'width': 10
}]
```

The following is an example with 3 blocks.

```
myblocks = [{
'blockCounter':1,
'x': 0,
'y': 0,
'height': 3
'width': 3
},
{'blockCounter':2,
'x': 3,
'y': 3,
'height': 3
'width': 7
}
{'blockCounter':3,
'x': 0,
'y': 4,
'height': 3
'width': 5
}
```

]

What is the best way to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:
I didn't test edge cases, but it should work fine (it worked for me :)..)
Its O(n) algorithm:

```
var cubes = [];
var rowSpace = (function () {
    let rowSpace = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < grid_width; i++) {
        rowSpace[i] = grid_width;
    }
    return rowSpace;
})();

function addBlock(block) {
    var minY = 0, maxY = 0, i;

    if (_isBlockValid(block)) {
        for (i = 0; i < rowSpace.length; i++) {
            if (rowSpace[i] >= block.width) {
                maxY++;
                if ((maxY - minY) >= block.height) {
                    _add(grid_width - rowSpace[i], minY, block);
                    _updateRows(minY, block.height, block.width);
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                minY++;
                maxY++;
            }
        }
    }

    //If you have got here, its because of an error
    console.log("no space available for: " + JSON.stringify(block));
}

function _isBlockValid(block) {
    return block && (typeof block.height === "number" && block.height >= block_min_height) &&
        (typeof block.height === "number" && block.width >= block_min_width);
}

function _add(x, y, block) {
    cubes.push({x, y, block});
}

function _updateRows(minY, rows, diff) {
    for (var i = minY; i < rows; i++) {
        rowSpace[i] -= diff;
    }
}

//Execution
for (var i = 0; i < myblocks.length; i++) {
    addBlock(myblocks[i]);
}
```